# Compiling vim with MinGW results in mingw-get install --reinstall binutils=2.22-1

Tags: vim, compilation, mingw, windres

I am trying to compile VIM with native support for ruby and am using MinGW for that.

The compilation goes as expected until the make file tries to execute `windres -DWIN32 -DWINVER=0x0400 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0400 ..... vim.rc gobj/vimres.res`

This step failes with a `windres: unexpected version string length 68 != 32 + 8`. I am at a complete loss what kind of error this is and how I am supposed to fix it.

As far as I can see I downloaded the newest version of both the vim sources and MinGW environment.

Searching the internet hinted me at trying to do a `mingw-get install --reinstall binutils=2.22-1` which I did. But I still get the same error message.

Comment: I'm not sure, but perhaps such extremely technical and localized problems are better suited for the [mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/vim_use) ...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the

```
mingw-get install --reinstall binutils=2.22-1
```

did not actually install a previous version.

Instead, with

```
mingw-get remove binutils
mingw-get install  binutils=2.22-1
```

I was able to install the previous version. Now, the `windres` step works.

Answer (score 0):

I just compiled Vim with MinGW/MSYS and among others dynamic ruby support. Check out this **[gist](https://gist.github.com/rpuntaie/8510218)** for a guide through the process with gvim74.exe installation file as output.